# Error trying to use WordsSegmenter.GetTokens()

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

The code:

WordsSegmenter s = new WordsSegmenter("en-US");
var words = s.GetTokens("The price of this API is €10,000.99.");

gives me a build error: "Error 2 The type 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I have System.Collections.Generic referenced and suspect that the error above is disguising the real problem.

I'm building this in Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop. Do I perhaps have to use VS Express for Windows?

Changing the target Framework of my project to other 4.x versions doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Two actions fixed this: Opening my project.csproj file in a text editor and changing the TargetPlatformVersion node to "8.1". Then added references to Windows.winmd and Windows.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll.
Kudos to Xavier H at Intel for this post: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications